# WP Admin pass url parameter to submit/post function

Tags: php, wordpress, parameter-passing, url-parameters

I have a WordPress Admin page where you can add a "listing" within this Admin Page I have added many fields which transfer variables over to the listing page which is created/updated. Within this admin page I am trying to take the string after the last "&" in the url which is manually enter in the url before loading the page
     see code below:

```
 $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
 $id = substr( $url, strrpos( $url, '&' )+1 );
```

NOW the code below here is called when the ABOVE admin page is submitted to update the "listing" what I need to do is somehow get the variable `$id` to pass through to this function and be used again within the submit code. Both of these functions are within functions.php so somehow it should be easy to do this!

This may not be "Wordpress Specific" but is a Wordpress Specific situation where I had this code working on a non-wordpress site. Please help!

```
    $dirname = "../wp-content/themes/Explorable/".$id."/"; 
  $images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents  
foreach($images as $image) {
 $imageNameLong = substr($image, -14);
$imageName = substr($imageNameLong,0 , -4);

 if ( isset( $_POST[$imageName.'links'] ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_'.$imageName.'links', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$imageName.'links'] ) );
        else
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_'.$imageName.'links' ); 

    if ( isset( $_POST[$imageName.'heading'] ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_'.$imageName.'heading', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$imageName.'heading'] ) );
        else
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_'.$imageName.'heading' ); 
};
```

Comment: what does `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` look like? It seems to me you are trying to access a `$_GET` variable, is that so?

Comment: the ONLY thing that is not working is that I'm trying to pass the url parameter `$id` to another function that is on the same page but doesnt seem to be passing that variable. How can i use `$id` within the other function?

Comment: can't you access the `id` by using `$_GET['var_id_name']`